# if $F_{\bullet}$ is a complex and $r$ an integer, what is $F_{r-\bullet}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, notation, homological-algebra

While reading the paper [Some results and questions on the Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~marc.chardin/publications/textes/24.survey-reg.pdf), by Marc Chardin, I encountered in the proof of Theorem 5.1 the notation $F^N_{r-\bullet}$. To provide some context, $N$ is a finitely generated graded module over a polynomial ring, $F^N_{\bullet}$ is its minimal graded free resolution, and $r$ is an integer. From the way the author is using the complex $F^N_{r-\bullet}$, it seems to me that this is $F^N_{\bullet}$ truncated at positions higher than $r$, and somehow considered as an ascending complex, i.e., the indices are now increasing (as opposed to the decreasing indices of the free modules appearing in a free resolution). It also seems that the degrees of the generators have now been reversed. Does anybody know the precise definition of $F^N_{r-\bullet}$? Thanks.

Comment: For me, if $F_\bullet$ is a chain complex then $F_{r-\bullet}$ is a cochain complex where $(F_{r-\bullet})_n = F_{r-n}$. Note that the differentials now increase degree.

Comment: @ZhenLin. Interesting, thanks.